# How can I tell if it is a cramp or tear?

Tags: muscle, cramps

Is there anyway I can tell a difference between a muscle cramp and a muscle tear?
I was running today on the treadmill, and decided to increase the speed a little bit, but after some time my left calf suddenly "froze" (thats the best description I can give), accompanied by a sudden but brief stab of pain, so I immediately stopped. I went on to stretch my legs a little bit, and was able to walk (although with some slight discomfort).
The area near the muscle is not swollen, but it is slightly tender and I can feel some slight twinging if I rotate my foot. Can someone please tell me if this is  a muscle tear or just a cramp?
It may be pertinent to mention that I did strength training yesterday focusing on my legs and calves.Also, I do drink a lot of water (>2L a day).
Should I wait before I can do anymore lower body exercise or can I continue if I feel OK?

Comment: This is off-topic for here (it's a medical question), but I would note that it sounded like nothing in particular right up until "tingling in my foot". That's nerve or blood supply related, and not a cramp.

Comment: Your best bet would be to see a sports doc or get a referral. A severe cramp and a slight tear can feel very similar, but have very different expected outcomes depending on how you pursue activity before full healing.

Comment: A nights rest seems to have done the job, I feel nearly back to normal. @EricKaufman The tingly/knotty sensation I had was on the calf muscle when I rotated my foot, not on the foot itself. That too is gone now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look like a muscle cramp to me, but we have to wait one more day to tell if it was a cramp. If the pain goes away, then it is a cramp, if not, it might be a tear. Here is more info:

> ### What is a Cramp?
>
> A cramp in a muscle is caused by an involuntary spasm or contraction. It is usually sudden, can cause significant pain and can limit the use of the muscle for a short period of time.
>
> ### Cramp Causes
>
> A cramp will present as a knot or hard spot in the muscle. Cramps are usually caused by problems such as overworking a muscle, poor hydration, electrolyte imbalances, insufficient blood flow to the muscle or nerve compression.
>
> ### What is a Muscle Tear?
>
> A pulled muscle is actually a tear in the muscle tissue. This occurs when the muscle is strained to the point where the muscle is damaged. The more significant the strain, the more the muscle can be torn.
>
> ### Pulled Muscle Causes
>
> Pulled muscles are usually the result of not preparing the muscle for work through proper stretching, placing too much tension on the muscle or over-using the muscle. Soreness in the affected muscle is usually the first symptom. Using the muscle will be painful and difficult. In severe pulls, bruising may be present. The affected muscle will become very tender to the touch and some swelling may occur.

[Reference](http://www.livestrong.com/article/38541-difference-between-pulled-muscle-/)

Comment: "_It look like a muscle cramp to me, but we have to wait one more day to tell if it was a cramp._" - And how did you come up with that diagnosis?

Comment: You are right I should have mentioned about it. +1.  Since the area near the muscle is not swollen, and he can walk, even there is a slight pain and more importantly "my left calf suddenly "froze" (stiffened I believe)" kind of symptoms show that it is more like a cramp.

Comment: Do you have a medical degree and the ability to diagnose over the internet?  I wouldn't make assumptions like that.

Comment: I completely ruptured my achilles. I was able to walk with slight discomfort.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that. Was it stiff? No. Because muscle only get stiff  and hard when it has a cramp. It is that simple :-). Also read the answer below "it was a cramp". Do not try to get everything complicated guys.